# Having trouble getting defaults write to output bools instead of strings

Tags: plist, defaults

We are trying to programmatically update user's pbs.plist file.  We took our desired command from plistwatch.  However, running the command is generating output into the plist as strings rather than booleans.  Is there a straightforward way to update the command so that it outputs booleans instead of the string "true"?  Thanks for your help.

```
defaults write pbs "NSServicesStatus" '{"com.techarrow.WinShortcutter - Open as Windows Link - doOpenLinkService"={"enabled_context_menu"=true;"enabled_services_menu"=true;"presentation_modes"={ContextMenu=true;ServicesMenu=true;};};}'
```